# Powershell script to deploy/move a wsp/solution file from local drive to SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, solution-deployment, farm-solution

I am new to an On-Prem environment. I am trying to automate the deploying or moving of Farm based solution and wsp packages from a local drive to SharePoint 2016 site collection.

I am a newbie to Powershell scripting.

Can someone please provide me with code to move the solution files from local drive and upload them to a SP 2016 site collection and also activate?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are u trying to install it or just copying it?

Comment: Deploy and activate the wsps.

Comment: your solution is on the shared drive not on the SharePoint server, right? if it is shared drive, do sharepoint services account have permission to that location?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Add-SPSolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/add-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps) and [Install-SPSolution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps) PowerShell commands.

Ex:

- Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath c:\solution1.wsp
- Install-SPSolution -Identity solution1.wsp -WebApplication http://webapurl  -GACDeployment

Answer (score 0):

You'd better refer the steps from the blog below to install wsp package to SharePoint with PowerShell:

[Add and Deploy Solution in SharePoint Central Administration Using PowerShell Commands](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/add-and-deploy-solution-in-sharepoint-central-administration/)

It has screen capture, easy to understand.